# Error uploading DateTime object to NoSQL database

Tags: database, datetime, flutter, dart, nosql

Hello all I am trying to upload a custom object with a DateTime object to a NoSQL databse (sembast) but am receiving an error of:

[image]

The custom object is as follows with the toMap constructor appearing to be the problem:

```
class Activity {
  final int id;
  final String name;
  final DateTime startTime;
  final DateTime endTime;
  final double sliderVal;
  final double countVal;
  final bool binaryVal;

  ...

  Map<String, dynamic> toMap() {
    return {
      'name': this.name,
      'startTime': this.startTime,
      'endTime': this.endTime,
      'sliderVal': this.sliderVal,
      'countVal': this.countVal,
      'binaryVal': this.binaryVal,
    };
  }
```

The code where the error happens is as follows:

```
import 'package:get_it/get_it.dart';
import 'package:sembast/sembast.dart';

import './activity.dart';
import './activity_repository.dart';

class SembastActivityRepository extends ActivityRepository {
  final Database _database = GetIt.I.get();
  final StoreRef _store = intMapStoreFactory.store("activity_list");

  @override
  Future<int> insertActivity(Activity activity) async {
    return await _store.add(_database, activity.toMap()); <<< ERROR HERE
  }
...
}
```

And I call the insertActivity constructor in another file and format it as follows:

```
abstract class ActivityRepository {
  Future<int> insertActivity(Activity activity);
  Future updateActivity(Activity activity);
  Future deleteActivity(int activityId);
  Future<List<Activity>> getAllActivities();
}

ActivityRepository _activityRepository = GetIt.I.get();

...

  _addActivity() async {
    final list = ['sleep', 'meditation', 'eating']..shuffle();
    final name = 'My awesome activity ${list.first}';
    final startTime = DateTime.now();
    final endTime = DateTime.now().add(new Duration(hours: 2));
    final sliderVal = Random().nextDouble() * 10;
    final countVal = Random().nextDouble() * 10;
    final binaryVal = Random().nextBool();
    final newActivity = Activity(
      name: name,
      startTime: startTime,
      endTime: endTime,
      sliderVal: sliderVal,
      countVal: countVal,
      binaryVal: binaryVal,
    );
 >>> await _activityRepository.insertActivity(newActivity);
    _loadActivities();
```

I'm not exactly sure why an "Instance of 'DateTime' " is appearing in the error if I only called a DateTime object. How can I fix this problem and upload all the data?

Comment: Sembast supports Timestamp instead that you convert to and from DateTime. https://pub.dev/documentation/sembast/latest/sembast_timestamp/Timestamp-class.html  , and https://github.com/tekartik/sembast.dart/issues/7

Answer (score 3):

As @chunhunghan noted, similarly to Firestore there is a Timestamp class that can easily convert `toDateTime()` and `fromDateTime(dateTime)`.

You could either (I would go for solution 2 personally):

1. Convert to Timestamp in toMap()

```dart
Timestamp _dateTimeToTimestamp(DateTime dateTime) =>
      dateTime != null ? Timestamp.fromDateTime(dateTime) : null;

Map<String, dynamic> toMap() {
  return {
    'name': name,
    'startTime': _dateTimeToTimestamp(startTime),
    'endTime': _dateTimeToTimestamp(endTime),
    'sliderVal': sliderVal,
    'countVal': countVal,
    'binaryVal': binaryVal,
  };
}
```

2. Use Timestamp everywhere

```dart
import 'package:sembast/timestamp.dart';

class Activity {
  final int id;
  final String name;
  final Timestamp startTime;
  final Timestamp endTime;
  final double sliderVal;
  final double countVal;
  final bool binaryVal;
  ...
}

Future _addActivity() async {
  final list = ['sleep', 'meditation', 'eating']..shuffle();
  final name = 'My awesome activity ${list.first}';
  final startTime = Timestamp.fromDateTime(DateTime.now());
  final endTime =
      Timestamp.fromDateTime(DateTime.now().add(Duration(hours: 2)));
  final sliderVal = Random().nextDouble() * 10;
  final countVal = Random().nextDouble() * 10;
  final binaryVal = Random().nextBool();
  final newActivity = Activity(
    name: name,
    startTime: startTime,
    endTime: endTime,
    sliderVal: sliderVal,
    countVal: countVal,
    binaryVal: binaryVal,
  );
  await _activityRepository.insertActivity(newActivity);
}
```

Comment: Awesome! Thanks so much! Is there an equivalent of DateTime.now() but with Timestamps? Just trying to clean the code a bit more.

Comment: `Timestamp.now();` !